Using timeDiff() to work out the difference between times and selecting ones that are over an hour out
I have a dataset of times which I am trying to compare, I have used timeDiff() to then work out the difference in times of the columns in my data. I now wish to select any times which are over an hour out from my original times. This is fine when times are are more than an hour out on the positive scale but when any times are displayed on the negative scale I'm struggling to get them.
dset
localtime             Tb_localtime           timeDiff
2024-08-17 11:00:00   2024-08-17 12:10:00    70
2024-08-17 13:00:00   2024-08-17 13:12:00    12
2024-08-17 11:00:00   2024-08-17 11:08:00    8
2024-08-17 13:00:00   2024-08-17 12:56:00    -4
2024-08-17 14:00:00   2024-08-17 12:58:00    -62
2024-08-17 14:30:00   NA                     NA

I've tried doing
which(dset$timeDiff > 60) #returns integer(0) 

I'm pretty sure this is due to the NAs in the data but am also sure its not the correct way to deal with the negative values.

Please use dput() to make your data reproducible.

This looks like a Dplyr filter() problem to me:
df1 <- dset |> filter(timeDiff > 60) df2 <- dset|> filter(timeDiff < 0) df <- rbind(df1,df2)


Did you mean difftime() instead of  " I have used timeDiff()" ? The the output of  difftime() is a time difference. My suggestion is to specify the units and transform as numeric : as.numeric(difftime(Tb_localtime, localtime, units = "mins" )) . For the negatives values, you can compare (  > ) with the absolute value abs(timeDiff)

No need for external packages. Simply use abs() in subset():
> subset(dset, abs(timeDiff) > 60L)
            localtime        Tb_localtime timeDiff
1 2024-08-17 11:00:00 2024-08-17 12:10:00       70
5 2024-08-17 14:00:00 2024-08-17 12:58:00      -62
## equivalent 
# dset[abs(dset$timeDiff) > 60L, ]


To filter rows where the time difference is more than 60 minutes (either positive or negative), you can use the abs() function in combination with is.na() to handle any missing values:
dset[!is.na(dset$timeDiff) & abs(dset$timeDiff) > 60, ]

